# 'progress' progress bar re-prints every iteration

Tags: r, progress-bar

When I use the package 'progress' like so:

```
library(progress)
pb <- progress_bar$new(total = 100)

for(i in 1:10){


pb$tick()
}
```

I get a repeated output like so:

[==>----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------]   3%[===>---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------]   4%[====>--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------]   5%[=====>-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------]   6%[======>------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------]   7%[=======>-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------]   8%[========>----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------]   9%[=========>---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------]  10%[==========>--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------]  11%[===========>-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------]  12%...

I would prefer it to delete the old bar after the new one is called. Is there a setting in R studio that I need to change to use that? I'm using a mac if that matters.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem, and it previously worked fine with the same code. Have you had any luck @Travasaurus?

Comment: Sorry @StuartAllen I have not :( I ended up using the function 'txtProgressBar' from utils instead.

Comment: Thanks @Travasaurus, appreciate the reply :)

Comment: This seems to work for me. What are your versions of R and of the progress package? You don't say so explicitly but I assume that you are seeing this output in the console, not recorded in some file?